# Pending Intent always return null for AlarmManager

Tags: android

I'm creating an alarm mananger that should run every day.
The alarm should only be set once, since the method is called in my MainActivity.But always the Pending intent return null.
I hoped that after it was created it would return the same pending intent, without having to set the alarm again.

```
public void setAlarm() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BroadcastLogRaces.class);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 99,
            intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (pi == null) {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);


        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pi);

        Log.i("alarme", "alarme agendado as "+ new Date().toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: "I hoped that after it was created..." - Where exactly are you creating the `PendingIntent`? Also, why are you trying to set the alarm only if it doesn't exist?

Comment: @MikeM. this method is called on onCreate of MainActivity

Comment: But you're not creating the `PendingIntent` there anywhere.

Comment: sorry I not understand... the PendingIntent was created in a method.... this block of code is in a method...

Comment: Now I'm not understanding. Are you saying you have a separate where the `PendingIntent` is being created? If so, you should show that method, too. Also, again, why are you only setting the alarm if the `PendingIntent` doesn't exist; i.e., `if (pi == null)`?

Comment: @MikeM. I update the code. I'm setting the alarm if the pending intent doesn't exist, because this method is called many times by MainActivity.

Comment: Right, but if the `PendingIntent` doesn't exist, you still need to create it. Setting the alarm doesn't create it. For example: `if (pi == null) { pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 99, intent, 0); Calendar calendar = ... }`

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, of course I need create. The problem is, after created, always the PendingIntent return NULL

Comment: You still have not shown us where or how you're creating the `PendingIntent`.

Comment: How no? in the code  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 99,
            intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

Comment: `FLAG_NO_CREATE` - What do you think that means? The answer below even has the docs description.

Answer (score 0):

You have used flag `FLAG_NO_CREATE` while creating your `PendingIntent`, it says

```
 /**
 * Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent does not
 * already exist, then simply return null instead of creating it.
 * For use with {@link #getActivity}, {@link #getBroadcast}, and
 * {@link #getService}.
 */
```

You need to use `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`or `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` which basically cancels current pending intent and replaces extra data if current pending intent still exists, respectively.

Comment: I understood that FLAG_NO_CREATE should return the intent if it exists, if there is no NULL return. No?

Comment: yes, But it already exists. That's the problem. Continues to return null.

Comment: Actually... If the intent exists, no create flag returns a null result. However if there is no matching intent ( check how intents are checked for equality on google... There's a bunch of things) is found, only then will a new intent get created.

Comment: Yes @AalapPatel, Always return different null. What I want is actually to create the alarm only once, set it only once.